# Managing autoload directories efficiently

Tags: neovim

There are a few questions intertwined -- I hope I convey my intentions well enough so that someone understands where I'm confused and what I'm trying to do. I apologize ahead of time for the chaotic state of this post.

I have **neovim** installed via homebrew (OSX/macOS).

I plan to use `nvim` exclusively as a replacement for `vim`, and I plan to utilise `gvim` once I sort out this confusion.

The directory `/usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.1.7/share/nvim/runtime` contains an `autoload` directory amongst much more:

├── autoload/
├── bugreport.vim
├── colors/
├── compiler/
├── delmenu.vim
├── doc/
├── filetype.vim
├── ftoff.vim
├── ftplugin/
├── ftplugin.vim
├── ftplugof.vim
├── indent/
├── indent.vim
├── indoff.vim
├── keymap/
├── macmap.vim
├── macros/
├── makemenu.vim
├── menu.vim
├── mswin.vim
├── optwin.vim
├── pack/
├── plugin/
├── print/
├── scripts.vim
├── synmenu.vim
├── syntax/
├── tutor/
└── vimrc_example.vim

When installing [vim-pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen), the installation leads you to create the directories `autoload` and `bundle` within the `~/.vim` directory.

I see that there are many important vim files in the `runtime` directory. I want to avoid redundancy as much as possible.

Would it be more efficient to symlink one/more of the directories in `~` to the `runtime` directory - or perhaps one/more of its subdirectories?

When installing vim plugins and other vim files to the config directory in my home directory, should I ensure that the same plugin files aren't located in both homebrew's `autoload` directory and `~/.vim/autoload`? In other words, do I need to verify beforehand that a particular vim file isn't already located in homebrew's `runtime` directory for `nvim` before installing said vim file in `~/.vim/`? Would it be more efficient to install all files in `~/.config/nvim` instead of `~/.vim`?

Should I modify the `execute pathogen#infect()` line in my `.vimrc` to reflect the runtime (or some other) directory?

I have `/usr/bin/vim` but not `vim` from homebrew. Would it make things easier if I installed homebrew's `vim` installed? This is something I eventually plan to do.

---

With `syntax on` in my `.vimrc` I receive this error every time I launch `vim` or `nvim`:

`Can't open file /usr/bin/vim/syntax/syntax.vim`

Yet `syntax.vim` exists within the `runtime` directory for `nvim` mentioned above.

---

What I have done so far:

- Per [here](https://neovim.io/doc/user/nvim.html#nvim-from-vim) I have

  ```
  mkdir ~/.config
  ln -s ~/.vim ~/.config/nvim
  ln -s ~/.vimrc ~/.config/nvim/init.vim
  ```
- In attempt to troubleshoot, I've started with a new `.vimrc` that contains

  ```
  execute pathogen#infect()
  syntax on
  filetype plugin indent on
  ```
- `pathogen.vim` is the only file located within `~/.vim/autoload`
- Variable `EDITOR` is set to `nvim` in `.bash_profile`
- I've reviewed [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4969/is-the-vim-directory-used-for-anything-other-than-plugins).

With `.vimrc` containing only the three lines above, I get the following errors when I run `vim` and `nvim`, respectively:

#### vim

```
    Error detected while processing /Users/user/.vimrc:
    line    2:
    E484: Can't open file /usr/bin/vim/syntax/syntax.vim
    Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

#### nvim

```
    Error detected while processing /Users/user/.config/nvim/init.vim:
    line    1:
    E117: Unknown function: pathogen#infect
    E15: Invalid expression: pathogen#infect()
    line    2:
    E484: Cannot open file /usr/bin/vim/syntax/syntax.vim
    Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

---

The ***ultimate*** question isn't necessarily surrounding `vim-pathogen`, but rather trying to find a sound way to understand and manage all configurations (including directories) between `vim`, `nvim`, `gvim`, etc.

I sincerely appreciate any help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're looking at this all wrong.  Read `:h 'runtimepath'`.

`'runtimepath'` or `'rtp'` is analogous to `$PATH` in the shell.  The files you see in `/usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.1.7/share/nvim/runtime` is the **pristine** runtime files that come with Neovim.  You **should not** add files to it.

If you want to see where scripts will be loaded from by default, run:

```
nvim -u NONE
```

Then

```
:echo &rtp
```

For Neovim, the default location is `$HOME/.config/nvim`.  The directory structure there is expected to be the same as what's described in `:h 'rtp'`.

Specific plugin managers aside, all they do is help you manage `'rtp'`.  As an example, say you want to use one of my plugins: [django-plus.vim](https://github.com/tweekmonster/django-plus.vim)

You will note that it has an `autoload`, `after`, and `doc` directory.  These aren't meant to be merged into a monolithic directory.  The entire repository is meant to be taken as-is in its own directory.  If you decided to download it and place it into `~/vim-plugins`, without a plugin manager, you would need to add it to `'rtp'` in your `init.vim` script:

```
set rtp+=~/vim-plugins/django-plus.vim
```

Now the plugin is "installed".  But, this is not the best method since it's being *appended* to the list.  Ideally it should be *prepended* because `django-plus.vim` has a script `filetype.vim` that should run *before* `$VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim` (like how `$PATH` is searched).  All plugins will want to be prepended to the `'rtp'` since the whole point is to override defaults.  This is where plugin managers help you manage all of this.

> I plan to use nvim exclusively as a replacement for vim, and I plan to utilise gvim once I sort out this confusion.

[Neovim has GUIs](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/Related-projects).

> With syntax on in my .vimrc I receive this error every time I launch vim or nvim:
>
> ```
> Can't open file /usr/bin/vim/syntax/syntax.vim
> ```

You somehow changed `'rtp'` or broke the runtime directories.  Again, confirm with `:echo &rtp`.

---

On the topic of plugin managers, just use [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug).  Everyone has their opinion about what the best plugin manager is, but I've *never* heard anyone say that `vim-plug` was hard to use.

```
call plug#begin('~/.local/share/nvim/plugged')
Plug 'tweekmonster/django-plus.vim'
" ...and so on...
call plug#end()
```

Then you run `:PlugUpdate` every now and then to keep things up to date.

Pathogen is minimalistic and leaves you still managing the plugins yourself.  There's people that like this, but I'm not among them.  I use *a lot* of plugins and I don't want to spend my time checking in on each one to see if they've been updated.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me wrap my head around this, and thanks for vim-plug. I was sure that I hadn't explicitly modified vim's `runtimepath`, but I did notice a line in my `.bash_profile`, `export VIM="$(command -v vim)"`. Changing this to `='/usr/local/share/vim/vim80'` seems to have worked (it fixed the errors vim/nvim was throwing). Does this send up any red flags in your opinion? Should this constant export be placed elsewhere? I also unlinked the sym link that I mentioned in my original post.

Comment: The runtime path is hardcoded in the binary.  See `:h $VIM`.  You shouldn't need to set `$VIM` at all unless you actually want to use a completely different set of runtime files (you probably don't).  [The only environment variable related to Vim you should be concerned with is `$EDITOR` and `$VISUAL`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4859/visual-vs-editor-whats-the-difference)