# Vim Indent and Syntax environment variables?

Tags: environment-variables

I was building CMake today and I saw in the install output:

```
-- Installing: /ford1/share/gmao_SIteam/Utilities/cmake-3.19.3/share/vim/vimfiles/indent
-- Installing: /ford1/share/gmao_SIteam/Utilities/cmake-3.19.3/share/vim/vimfiles/indent/cmake.vim
-- Installing: /ford1/share/gmao_SIteam/Utilities/cmake-3.19.3/share/vim/vimfiles/syntax
-- Installing: /ford1/share/gmao_SIteam/Utilities/cmake-3.19.3/share/vim/vimfiles/syntax/cmake.vim
```

So that got me to thinking. Is there a vim environment variable (`VIM_INDENTPATH`?) or the like that I could `setenv` in my environment and/or Lua modules so that when I `module load cmake/3.19.3` Vim would see these files dynamically?

(Or perhaps, should I just ignore these in case they aren't as maintained as I hope?)

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/23136/22797

Comment: I think you're looking for `runtimepath`; [this is a reasonably nice explanation](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/11127/51) of how this works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Managing autoload directories efficiently](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/11124/managing-autoload-directories-efficiently)

Comment: Eh, I'm not convinced that's the best answer @MartinTournoij—with programs that come with their own vimfiles, there's often some way of putting them in a `share` directory (via symlink) that vim will include in it's `rtp` to pick up such files. With brew on my mac, `/usr/local/share/vim/vimfiles` has some interesting stuff.

Comment: I think that updating `'runtimepath'` to include the `/ford1/share/gmao_SIteam/Utilities/cmake-3.19.3/share/vim/vimfiles` directory is the right approach here, but I guess the question is how to connect `module` exporting that directory as part of an environment variable and then Vim/NeoVim using that environment variable to populate `'runtimepath'` to include those directories... There's no environment variable that does that by default, but this could be done by a snippet in the vimrc processing it.